# Erro em algoritmo EM com loop while

Tags: r, while

Olá, o meu projeto precisa do algoritmo EM abaixo, onde está todos os códigos. O erro está no *loop* `while`, que é onde estão as etapas esperança e maximização. A mensagem de erro é:

> "Error in while (abs(Elogv[r] - Elogv[r - 1]) >= 1e-06) { :
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"**.

Como faço pra resolver esse erro, se o loop `while` não contém comandos `TRUE` e `FALSE` e, se já verifiquei detalhadamente que não há nenhum erro nos comandos e não há valor `NA`s?

Código:

```
n=100
u<-runif(n)
QUANTIL <- function(u){
  Q <- rep(NA, length(u))
  for (i in 1:length(u)) {
    if(u[i] <  0.2634253829){
      Q[i] <- 1*tan(pi*(0.9490353482*u[i]-0.5))+0
    }
    if(u[i]>=0.2634253829 && u[i] < 0.7365746171){
      Q[i] <-  1*qnorm(1.4428629504*u[i]-0.2214315)+0
    }
    if(u[i]>0.7365746171){
      Q[i] <- 1*tan(pi*(0.9490353482*u[i]-0.4490353))+0
    } 
  }
  return(Q)
}
x<-QUANTIL(u)
y<-c(sort(x))
i<-seq(1,n)
v<-c(i/(n+1))

t<-QUANTIL(v)
mi<-median(y)
s<-c(y[26:73])
sigma<-sqrt(sum((s-mi)^2)/(n-1))
p=0.4731492342

alpha<-(2*t^3)/(1+t^2)^2
beta<-(1-t^2)/(1+t^2)^2
eta<-(t^4-t^2)/(1+t^2)^2
lambda<-2*t/(1+t^2)^2
gama<-(-t^2)
delta<-2*t

k<-((p*0.6930665173/sigma*sqrt(2*pi))*exp((-1/2*sigma^2)*((y-mi)^2)))/(((p*0.6930665173/sigma*sqrt(2*pi))*exp((-1/2*sigma^2)*(y-mi)^2))+((((1-p)*1.0537015317/sigma*pi))*(1/(1+((y-mi)/sigma)^2))))
r<-2
Elogv<-sum(k*((-1/2)*((y-mi)/sigma)^2))-sum(k*log(sigma*sqrt(2*pi)))-sum((1-k)*log(sigma*pi))-sum((1-k)*log(1+((y-mi)/sigma)^2))+sum(k*log(p))+(n-sum(k))*log(1-p)+log(0.6930665173)*sum(k)+log(1.0537015317)*sum(1-k)
Elogv[1]<-0

while (abs(Elogv[r]-Elogv[r-1])>=0.000001) {

  w<-(2*beta-2*k*beta+k)
  q<-k*delta+2*lambda*(1-k)
  sigma<-(sum(y*w)*sum(q)-sum(w)*sum(y*q))/(-2*sum(alpha*(1-k))*sum(q)+sum(w)*sum(k*gama-1)+2*sum(w)*sum(eta*(1-k)))                                                  
  mi<-(sum(y*w)+2*sigma*sum(alpha*(1-k)))/sum(w)
  k<-((p*0.6930665173/sigma*sqrt(2*pi))*exp((-1/2*sigma^2)*((y-mi)^2)))/(((p*0.6930665173/sigma*sqrt(2*pi))*exp((-1/2*sigma^2)*(y-mi)^2))+((((1-p)*1.0537015317/sigma*pi))*(1/(1+((y-mi)/sigma)^2))))
  Elogv[r]<-sum(k*((-1/2)*((y-mi)/sigma)^2))-sum(k*log(sigma*sqrt(2*pi)))-sum((1-k)*log(sigma*pi))-sum((1-k)*log(1+((y-mi)/sigma)^2))+sum(k*log(p))+(n-sum(k))*log(1-p)+log(0.6930665173)*sum(k)+log(1.0537015317)*sum(1-k)
  r<-r+1
  

}
```

Comment: Eu desconheço um programa que interprete algorítimos. O nome do programa é Algorítimo EM? Se for onde eu faço o download e onde encontro a documentação?

Comment: Esse algoritmo EM não tem documentação, é teoria estatística, deve ter um pacote pronto mas nao está usado aí, está feito manualmente. O ponto central do problema é o loop while que está na parte final do algoritmo, que causa a mensagem de erro. Eu coloquei o código todo pra se alguém quiser rodar o loop while, pois necessitaria dos códigos desde o início.

Comment: Eu não sou especialista em "R", não sei nada sobre ,mas sei ler documentação e caçar bugs. Na documentação diz o erro acontece poque sua comparação retorna o valor `NA` e uma alternativa é utilizar o método `isTRUE` que retorna o valor lógico da expressão e manipula o resultado caso retorne `NA`.Ficaria: `while (isTRUE(abs(Elogv[r]-Elogv[r-1])>=0.000001, na=FALSE))`

Comment: Deixo como comentário e não como uma resposta pois eu não sei nada sobre `r` e seria leviano da minha parte afirmar uma resposta. Então deixo um comentário com a minha opinião e espero que ajude.

Answer (score -2):

> Como faço pra resolver esse erro, se o loop while não contém comandos TRUE e FALSE e, se já verifiquei detalhadamente que não há nenhum erro nos comandos e não há valor NAs?

O `While` é uma estrutura de repetição que necessita de que uma condição lógica seja atendida para ser executado. Para ser mais claro, ele basicamente só vai repetir enquanto a condição apresentada, no seu caso, `(abs(Elogv[r]-Elogv[r-1])>=0.000001)`, for verdadeira.

Para mais informação sobre `While`: (https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#while)

Para sermos mais precisos, podemos dizer que o seu problema está na lógica de programação.

A variável `Elogv` foi iniciada recebendo valores de um somatório que na sequência foi substituído pelo valor `0` indicado na posição `[1]`, `Elogv[1]<-0`, transformando também essa variável num vetor neste momento.

De acordo com a sua condição `While`, `(abs(Elogv[r]-Elogv[r-1])>=0.000001)`, enquanto o valor absoluto de `Elogv` na posição `[r]` menos `Elogv` na posição `[r-1]` for maior ou igual a `0.000001` será feito o que estiver dentro das chaves`{}`.

Portanto, ela nunca será atendida, pois, sendo `r` igual a `2`, logo `Elogv[2]` é igual a `Na`, porque em nenhum momento foi atribuído algum valor na posição `[2]`, e `Elogv[2-1]`, isto é, `Elogv[1]` é igual a `0`, por isso nunca serão maior que `0`.

Mas cuidado, embora pareça que o resultado deveria ser falso ao invés de emitir erro, você precisa se atentar que como não é possível subtrair um valor por outro que está como `Na` (Not available/Não disponível) na linguagem R, o resultado é `Na`. Por isso que acusou o erro dizendo que não foram encontrados valores onde `TRUE` (verdadeiro) ou `FALSE` (falso) são necessários. A condição não resultou em verdadeiro ou falso, apenas em `Na`.

Para resolver o problema você precisará entender a lógica necessária para o desenvolvimento do seu algoritmo, porque se prosseguirmos com a análise do script é possível notar que não bastará acabar com o alerta de erro acertando a  atribuição inicial da variável, observe que dentro do `While` ocorrerá mais um `Na` devido a variável `r` ser acrescentada sem que `Elogv` receba atribuição de valor, logo `Elogv[3]` será igual a `Na`.

Para mais informação sobre `Na`: (https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#NA-handling)

Além dessas observações, outro ponto importante são os cálculos, você precisa analisar se eles não resultarão num dado contínuo que fará com que o seu `While` nunca tenha fim.

Segue abaixo uma alternativa para acabar com o erro, lembrando que você precisa entender a lógica desse programa para poder fazer os devidos ajustes corretamente. Não é porque não emitirá erro que o código estará cumprindo 100% com o seu objetivo.

```
#inicia o vetor
Elogv <- vector()
#atribui valor na posição 1 do vetor
Elogv[1]<-0
#atribui valor na posição 2 do vetor
Elogv[2]<-sum(k*((-1/2)*((y-mi)/sigma)^2))-sum(k*log(sigma*sqrt(2*pi)))-sum((1-k)*log(sigma*pi))-sum((1-k)*log(1+((y-mi)/sigma)^2))+sum(k*log(p))+(n-sum(k))*log(1-p)+log(0.6930665173)*sum(k)+log(1.0537015317)*sum(1-k)

while (abs(Elogv[r]-Elogv[r-1])>=0.000001) {
  w<-(2*beta-2*k*beta+k)
  q<-k*delta+2*lambda*(1-k)
  sigma<-(sum(y*w)*sum(q)-sum(w)*sum(y*q))/(-2*sum(alpha*(1-k))*sum(q)+sum(w)*sum(k*gama-1)+2*sum(w)*sum(eta*(1-k)))                                                  
  mi<-(sum(y*w)+2*sigma*sum(alpha*(1-k)))/sum(w)
  k<-((p*0.6930665173/sigma*sqrt(2*pi))*exp((-1/2*sigma^2)*((y-mi)^2)))/(((p*0.6930665173/sigma*sqrt(2*pi))*exp((-1/2*sigma^2)*(y-mi)^2))+((((1-p)*1.0537015317/sigma*pi))*(1/(1+((y-mi)/sigma)^2))))
  #foi invertido a ordem do r e Elogv
  r<-r+1
  Elogv[r]<-sum(k*((-1/2)*((y-mi)/sigma)^2))-sum(k*log(sigma*sqrt(2*pi)))-sum((1-k)*log(sigma*pi))-sum((1-k)*log(1+((y-mi)/sigma)^2))+sum(k*log(p))+(n-sum(k))*log(1-p)+log(0.6930665173)*sum(k)+log(1.0537015317)*sum(1-k)
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).